# get only one value for customer_ID where multiple rows for where

Tags: mysql, group-by, dbvisualizer, mysql-error-1055

Hi all this is my query - if I run this I get multiple customer ids but I just want to select one customer id

```
SELECT payments.customer_id,
       payments.reason,
       payments.date
FROM payments  
WHERE reason like '%error%' 
ORDER BY payments.date DESC
```

This is the error message I get if i try to use a group by

> `Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'reason' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (errno 1055) (sqlstate 42000)`

Comment: Could you add some data, and your query doesn't contain any Group  By Clause, but data so that we can see what result you get and where it comes from  is necessary.

Comment: that is always a problem, so you have to do some work and anonymize it.

Comment: i think i need a group by with customer_id but it keeps on throwing an error

Comment: It is hard to gues without any data, but grouping by customer_id is a good start and try an aggregathion for the rest of the columns like Group_:concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need below -

```
SELECT p.customer_id,
       p.reason,
       MAX(p.date) max_date
FROM payments p
WHERE p.reason like '%error%' 
GROUP BY p.customer_id,
         p.reason
ORDER BY max_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT payments.customer_id, 
                payments.reason,
                payments.date FROM payments
WHERE reason like '%error%' 
ORDER BY payments.date DESC
```

DISTINCT will solve this for you

Comment: thanks Arun and Badmous -  I tried to use distinct already but I still get multiple customer ids . I think this might happen because declined reason appears several time for the same customer. Im trying to get one error for one customer_id